# React-hook-form Uncontrolled error when using input mask with material UI textfield

Tags: material-ui, textfield, react-hook-form, input-mask

when I'm using a controller with input mask and a text field of the material I can't access the errors at the time of submit.

I already tried to put a default value that they suggested in some similar questions but it didn't work.

Below I left some examples.

[Follow the code and image below.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FvcVV.png)

```
import { TextField } from "@mui/material";
import { Controller } from "react-hook-form";
import InputMask from "react-input-mask";

const InputCustom = ({
  control,
  errorFieldMessage,
  name,
  mask,
  label,
}: any) => {
  return (
    <Controller
      name={name}
      control={control}
      defaultValue=""
      render={({ field: { onChange, value } }) => (
        <InputMask mask={mask} value={value} onChange={onChange}>
          {(inputProps: any) => (
            <TextField
              error={!!errorFieldMessage}
              helperText={errorFieldMessage}
              label={label}
              variant="outlined"
              type="text"
              fullWidth
              required
              {...inputProps}
            />
          )}
        </InputMask>
      )}
    />
  );
};
```

when I leave it without the mask and submit, it works.
[Follow the code and image below.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Me3W.png)

```
import { TextField } from "@mui/material";
import { Controller } from "react-hook-form";
import InputMask from "react-input-mask";
const InputCustom = ({
  control,
  errorFieldMessage,
  name,
  mask,
  label,
}: any) => {
  return (
    <Controller
      name={name}
      control={control}
      defaultValue=""
      render={({ field: { onChange, value } }) => (
        <TextField
          error={errorFieldMessage}
          label={label}
          variant="outlined"
          type="text"
          fullWidth
          required
          onChange={onChange}
          value={value}
        />
      )}
    />
  );
};
```

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution since 2022 ?